# What is the chance of one player winning a tournament, when different players have different skill levels?

Tags: probability

There are 8 players at the beginning of an elimination tournament.

Two players in particular, A and B, have a 2/3 chance of winning against any other player.  A has a 3/5 chance of winning against B.

If A and B meet, they can only do so in the final.

What is the chance of A winning the tournament (not necessarily against B)?
And vice versa?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eight players means that we have 3 "levels" of matches: Quarterfinals, semifinals, and the final. Thus, player A needs 2 wins to get to the final. So it has probability ${2 \over 3} \cdot {2 \over 3}  = {4 \over 9}$ to reach the final (since it will only play against players other than B)

Then it can either play against player B or any other player. Player B has also 4/9 probability to reach the final.  So the probability of player A winning is: 
$$\frac{4}{9}\cdot \left( \frac{4}{9}\cdot\frac{3}{5} + \frac{5}{9}\cdot\frac{2}{3} \right) = \frac{344}{1215} \approx 0.283 $$

Similarly for player B the probability of winning is:

$$\frac{4}{9}\cdot \left( \frac{4}{9}\cdot\frac{2}{5} + \frac{5}{9}\cdot\frac{2}{3} \right) = \frac{296}{1215} \approx 0.247 $$

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much!

Comment: @ThreeOneFour I forgot to ask you earlier, what have you tried and where were you stuck?

Comment: I had tried making a tree diagram and tried something to do with the chance that the two players would end up meeting each other.  I was a bit confused.  Your answer explains it perfectly though, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are 8 players, so two rounds before the final. For A and B, the chance of them reaching the final is $(\frac{2}{3})^2$ = $\frac{4}{9}$, and the chance of not making the final $\frac{5}{9}$.

A wins $\frac{4}{9}*\frac{4}{9}*\frac{3}{5}$ vs B, and $\frac{4}{9}*\frac{5}{9}*\frac{2}{3}$ against someone else, ~28.31%.

Similarly B wins $\frac{4}{9}*\frac{4}{9}*\frac{2}{5}$ vs A, and $\frac{4}{9}*\frac{5}{9}*\frac{2}{3}$ against someone else, ~24.36%.